# Help understanding path taken by APRS packet

Tags: aprs

I'm looking at some raw APRS packets over APRS-IS. I'd like to determine which stations heard particular packets, but I'm having trouble understanding how TNC-2 paths work. Here are two examples:

```
2016-05-19 05:51:46 PDT: PACCTY>APN390,HEBOWX,KFALLS,OR2*,qAR,STUKEL:
2016-05-19 05:55:32 PDT: PACCTY>APN390,WIDE1-1,OR2-1,qAR,W7GC-4:
```

Can you explain how I can determine the actual path the packet took? Also, how do I differentiate this from the path that the sender, `PACCTY` requested?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the way things work for simple AX.25 packets, the part after ">" is the destination address.  However, the APRS specification commonly repurposes fields, with the goal being to keep the packet as small as possible.  The destination field is like that: most APRS packets are broadcast rather than sent to a specific station, so when an APRS packet isn't meant for a specific station then the destination field is pressed into service to hold something else.  If the "destination" starts with AP, then it's a code that indicates what device or software package sent the packet.  In this case, a "destination" of the pattern APN3xx means that the packet was sent by a Kantronics KPC-3.  (The destination can also be Mic-E encoded, in which case it holds the latitude and part of the longitude of the sending station, plus a few other miscellaneous data flags.)

Similarly, `WIDE1-1` doesn't actually mean that the packet was repeated by a station of that name.  In this case, `WIDE1-1` is an instruction for how to repeat the packet, which was part of the packet when it was first sent.  It requests that a "wide" digipeater (one with a wide coverage area, like on a mountaintop) repeat the packet, but only once; if a second "wide" digipeater should hear the rebroadcast packet, then the second digipeater wouldn't repeat it.

Apparently `qAR` is the "Q-construct" that indicates that the packet was was successfully "Igated" to APRS-IS, the APRS internet packet routing system.

I'm reasonably familiar with APRS, but not an expert.  Even so I'll give the second part of your question a go, but I reserve the right to be wrong ;)

`PACCTY>APN390,HEBOWX,KFALLS,OR2*,qAR,STUKEL:` This packet was sent by PACCTY using a Kantronics KPC-3.  It was digipeated by HEBOWX, KFALLS, and OR2, and then copied onto APRS-IS, the internet APRS packet network, by STUKEL.  It's unlikely that that exact path was requested by the sender; it's more likely that the original path request was `WIDE1-1,WIDE2-1`.  `WIDE1-1` is a request for a small home digipeater to rebroadcast the packet.  `WIDE2-1` is a request for a high-up digipeaters to rebroadcast.  Each station that rebroadcasts the packet puts its call sign into the path.

`PACCTY>APN390,WIDE1-1,OR2-1,qAR,W7GC-4:`  Here we have a packet that was never digipeated before being copied to the internet; we can tell because there is no asterisk.  The original packet was heard by Igate W7GC-4 and copied onto APRS-IS there.  (The packet probably was digipeated, but when multiple copies of a packet are received on APRS-IS, then one is chosen at random to be kept, and the rest are ignored as being redundant.)

Because this packet was copied to APRS-IS before being digipeated, we have a better look at the original path request.  As I suspected, `WIDE1-1` is in there first as an invitation for small home digipeaters to repeat the packet.  Next comes `OR2-1`.  That could be a station OR2 with an SSID of "-1".  But given that the first packet didn't contain `OR2-1`, it seems like it is more likely to be an alias.  Maybe it works like `WIDE2-1`, but just in Oregon?  I'm not sure.

Just for grins, let's look again at the first packet and assume that it was sent with `WIDE1-1,WIDE2-1` to see how digipeaters modify the packets going through them.

`PACCTY>APN390,WIDE1-1,WIDE2-1:` original packet
`PACCTY>APN390,HEBOWX*,WIDE2-1:` packet was heard and digipeated by HEBOWX, which responded to the alias WIDE1 and substituted its own call sign
`PACCTY>APN390,HEBOWX,KFALLS*:` packet was heard and digipeated by KFALLS, responding to the alias WIDE2
`PACCTY>APN390,HEBOWX,KFALLS,OR2*,qAR,STUKEL:` packet was heard and copied to APRS-IS (but not digipeated) by STUKEL

Comment: Thanks! I've edited my question to be a bit more useful to others. I'm wondering how I can determine which path the packet actually took, which IGate it went through, and how many times it was digipeated.

Comment: This helps a lot. Now I'm understanding the rest of what I've been reading. Based on that, I think OR2-1 is a [local state or province aliases referred to as SSn-N](http://aprsisce.wikidot.com/menu:configure-aliases). In the first packet, I believe a Fill-In digipeater, or relay, performed the last hop and decremented what was OR2-1 but didn't substitute it's own callsign (Fill-In digipeaters don't usually?).

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for filling in the last piece of the puzzle with the SSn-N info.  I'd forgotten most of this stuff, so it was nice to go through the refresher course in answering your question ;)  Now if only people would use APRS to send *and receive* local tactical information instead of just broadcasting the locations of their cars...

Comment: I have two questions for rclocher3: 1. In paragraph 2 you say "WIDE1-1 ... requests that a "wide" digipeater (one with a wide coverage area, like on a mountaintop) repeat the packet" but then near the end you say "WIDE1-1 is in there first as an invitation for small home digipeaters to repeat the packet". Which is correct? 2. What reference are you "refreshing" from? It sounds like a great read.

Comment: I'm glad to see that someone's paying attention...  You caught my own understanding evolving as I wrote my answer.  It turns out that WIDE1-1 is the replacement for the old RELAY alias.  In other words, WIDE1-1 is an alias for small home digipeaters.  WIDE2-1 is an alias for a true "wide" digipeater on a mountaintop.  As for my references, [here](http://wsanders.net/aprsunproto.html) [are](http://wa8lmf.net/DigiPaths/) [some](http://www.aprs.org/).