# Direwolf APRS decoding unknown data

Tags: aprs, direwolf

I've read the APRS spec, but can't for the life of me figure out where Direwolf is getting certain info. Looking at the output below:

```
Digipeater ZS6PJH-2 audio level = 55(23/12)   [NONE]   _____:|__
[0.6 11:24:46] ZS6JV-2>APDW17,ZS0ERB-5,ZS6PJH-2*,WIDE2-1:;ZS6JV-2  *111111z2638.28S\02756.20E&Internet Gateway
Object, "ZS6JV-2", I=Igte IGate R=RX T=1hopTX 2=2hopTX, DireWolf, WB2OSZ
S 26 38.2800, E 027 56.2000
Internet Gateway
mheard_save_rf: ZS6JV-2 2 - update time, was 2 hops 5 seconds ago.
callsign  cnt chan hops    RF      IS    lat     long  msp
ZS6JV-2     9   0   2     0:00    0:04  -26.64   27.94  0
ZS4OIL-1   15   0   2     0:00     -    -26.69   27.81  0
ZR6N-1      9   0   1     0:01     -    -26.10   28.02  0
ZS6MJS-10   7   0   0     0:03     -    -25.79   28.31  0
ZS0ERB-5    1   0   1     0:10     -    -26.39   28.00  0
ZS6BVJ-9   30   0   0     2:30     -    -25.78   28.32  0
ZS6JCO-1    2   0   4     2:37     -    -26.77   27.84  0
[0H 11:24:46] ZS6JV-2>APDW17,ZS0ERB-5,ZS6PJH-2,ZS6MJS-10*:;ZS6JV-2  *111111z2638.28S\02756.20E&Internet Gateway
```

I can't see which part of the APRS packet:

```
ZS6JV-2>APDW17,ZS0ERB-5,ZS6PJH-2*,WIDE2-1:;ZS6JV-2  *111111z2638.28S\02756.20E&Internet Gateway
```

Decodes to the below:

```
I=Igte IGate R=RX T=1hopTX 2=2hopTX
```

Comment: Please see the related question [Help understanding path taken by APRS packet](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/6213/help-understanding-path-taken-by-aprs-packet).  Does the information there answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

The `\` and `&` after the latitude and the longitude respectively make up the symbol: `\&`. The descriptions that direwolf displays for symbols come from the data files `symbolsX.txt` and `symbols-new.txt` which are sourced from aprs.org.

The description for `\&` in `symbolsX.txt` is `I=Igte R=RX T=1hopTX 2=2hopTX`, which is where that's coming from, but it turns out to be quite a confusing message. It's in that file to convey the fact that `I&` should be used to mean "generic igate", `R&` to mean "RX-only igate", `T&` to mean "TX igate (with a 1-hop path)", and `2&` to mean "TX igate (with a 2-hop path)"... and that `\&` is no longer recommended for use as a symbol. Direwolf is kind of displaying it out of context here. Usually the descriptions are more immediately useful.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a bunch.